# Creating items with listpicker

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1, listpicker

I have a problem with this. I'm creating a unit converter. I've created 3 listpicker:

1st Type of measure
2nd From
3rd To

It's add the items but for example if I want select "weight" i want that it shows "Kilograms" and "Pounds"

I show you the code:

```
    convtypelp.Items.Add("Weight")
    convtypelp.Items.Add("Speed")

    If convtypelp.SelectedItem = "Weight" Then
        convfromlp.Items.Add("Kilograms")
        convfromlp.Items.Add("Pounds")
        convtolp.Items.Add("Kilograms")
        convtolp.Items.Add("Pounds")

    ElseIf convtypelp.SelectedItem = "Speed" Then
        convfromlp.Items.Add("Knots")
        convfromlp.Items.Add("KPH")
        convfromlp.Items.Add("MPH")
        convtolp.Items.Add("Knots")
        convtolp.Items.Add("KPH")
        convtolp.Items.Add("MPH")
    End If
```

When I execute the app to test appears the following error:

> Requested operation is not available because the runtime library function `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual`

Comment: does this error occur while on selection of items or directly when you launch the app?

Comment: Hello Karthik. It happen when launch the app.

Comment: try adding .ToString() before comparing in your if else condition e.g If convtypelp.SelectedItem.ToString() = "Weight" Then

Comment: Hello Karthik. Sorry for the delay i was on a trip. I tried this but only shows from weight.It doesn´t show for speed.

Comment: it is possible that some other code is messing things up...

Comment: Hello Karthik. I´ve found the reason. I had to add the event SelectionChanged. Now i can see the differents options.Many thanks for all.